# ImageButtons In GrdView Different Screen Sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

I am reviewing and fixing some issues at an Android application that was developed from other developer.

He created a screen layout for normal screen size and inserted a `GridView` in it.

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="45dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:columnWidth="120dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
/>
```

At code side images defined as `integer` array.

```
Integer[] a1 = {                R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3,R.drawable.image4,                R.drawable.image5,R.drawable.image6,R.drawable.image6,R.drawable.image7,R.drawable.image8,              R.drawable.image9,R.drawable.image10,R.drawable.image11
        };
```

Integer array binded gridview with this code.

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);     
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageButtonAdapter(this,infox));
```

So here ise ImageButtonAdapter class

```
public class ImageButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;

        public ImageButtonAdapter(Context c, Integer[] imageIds) {
            mContext = c;           
            mThumbIds = imageIds;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ImageButton imageButtonx;
            if (convertView == null) {  
                imageButtonx = new ImageButton(mContext);
                imageButtonx.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);                         
                **imageButtonx.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(160, 160));**
                imageButtonx.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageButtonx.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                /* if ( position == 10 )
                {
                    imageButtonx.setVisibility(ImageButton.GONE);
                }
                */

            } else {
                imageButtonx = (ImageButton) convertView;
            }

                setMyTag(imageButtonx,mThumbIds[position]);
            imageButtonx.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

            return imageButtonx;
            }
        private Integer[] mThumbIds;
    }
```

Also, res\drawable-hdpi folder contains high resolution images that is 167x161 px and res\drawable-mdpi folder contains normal resolution images that is 82x72 px.

But at small screened devices, images streched. I think the bold code line cause this; but i couldn't fix it.

Do you have any suggestion how can i fix this problem and support large-normal and small screens?

Comment: why you cant give some thing like this instead view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Comment: because i don't that option; let me try :)

Comment: thank you, this solved my problem; but i couldn't mark as answer because you posted as comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

This is what i normally do, hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

yes due to this you are getting that problem

```
imageButtonx.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(160, 160))
```

change this code like this

```
imageButtonx.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
                      (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.width),                                                                                   
                      (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.height)));
```

store width, height value in the `values-->dimentions.xml` folder like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="width">80dp</dimen>  // your desired values 
   <dimen name="height">80dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

HTH..

Comment: Can values folder be used like values-small or values-mdpi. If not i couldn't find any sense to write values harcoded or define in resource file. I hope you can explain

Comment: no need it will be automatically adjust depending on screen sizes if we use as DP...

Comment: really, i will try and let you know about result.